# I want my sharing file client have only read permission and I want client to not copy my file

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2

Our office has some file sharing client - he can read that file and he copy  file his computer.

Now I want the client to have only read permission, copy permission should be denied

I use Windows 7 operating system. Server is Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: Impossible.... if he can read it from your server to view it on his computer, his computer can then save a copy of what it is viewing, and your server has no control over that.

Comment: One very complex way to do it is by implementing DRM. However, some DRM like the ones used in PDF is broken since open source app have switch to ignore it, and nothing stop your user to just capture the screen and OCR them afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible - there is no "copy" bit - you can either acquire the contents of the file or not - how the computer processes it is not up to the file server.

You might be able to get away with forcing access to be through a terminal only, and ensure that the terminal has no storage to copy the file onto - but, of-course, the analog hole still exists - there is nothing stopping the person taking a photograph of the screen.